# Цикл for в python. Изменение I в цикле

Tags: python

```
for i in range(7):
print(i)
if True:
    i+=5
```

Ответ:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

`i+=5` не изменяет `for`.
Как сделать,чтобы ответ стал

```
0
5
```

Comment: почему именно такой ответ должен быть?

Comment: `for i in range(0, 7, 5):`

Answer (score 0):

`i` изменяется. Вот только на следующем цикле в переменную `i` будет присвоено очередное значение из ряда `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)` согласно вашему `range(7)`.

Если требуется просто идти с некоторым шагом, то используй соответствующие параметры для функции `range()`. Например, цикл:

```
for i in range(0, 7, 5):
    ...
```

будет идти от 0 до 7 с шагом 5.

Если же вам требуется управлять шагом внутри цикла, то делайте это при помощи цикла `while`:

```
i = 0
while i < 7:
    if True:
        i += 5
    else:
        i += 1
    ...
```